# How do I pass my components theme through storybook?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, storybook

I need to pass a theme that is used in components but I get a syntax error.

My .storybook/config.js:

```
import { configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'
import React from 'react'

import theme from '../src/theme'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import '../src/styles/index.css'

addDecorator(story => <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{story()}</ThemeProvider>)

function loadStories() {
  const req = require.context('../src', true, /\.stories.js$/)
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename))
}

configure(loadStories, module)
```

Here's the full error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the latest version of storybook ?

Comment: I think so. I followed the instructions on storybook's website.

Comment: Can you post your Webpack configuration, please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the theme provider as a separate file without using the decorators? The below is a Styled-components and typescript implementation.

```
import React from 'react';  

export const Container = ({ title, children }) => {
   return (
    <StoryWrapper>
      <GlobalStyle theme={themes.default} />

        <ThemeProvider theme={themes.default}>
          <MainWrapper>
            <Header>{title}</Header>
            {children}
          </MainWrapper>
        </ThemeProvider>

    </StoryWrapper>
  );
};
```

I never used the add decorator feature and this was the config implementation I used, it is set up for tsx though.

```
import { addParameters, configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

const req = require.context('../src', true, /.stories.tsx$/);
function loadStories(){
    req.keys().forEach(req);
}

addDecorator(withKnobs);

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Babel is confused that you're using JSX in a JS file.

Try renaming `config.js` to `config.jsx`. The file extension should instruct babel to treat it as a JSX file.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried that, doesn't help